# Do you find "only belongings of somebody" a little bit wierd?

Tags: nouns, countable-nouns, collective-nouns, quantifiers, pluralia-tantum

In the sentence below, do you think it is weird to say "only belongings" for "belongings" is a collective noun.

> The angry mob destroyed the man's only belongings.

Comment: or ..... the only belongings of the man.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up the word *only* in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. It's idiomatic; '... all the man's belongings' works but doesn't sound as empathetic. ' ... all that he possessed [not a lot to begin with]'.